# remove header and add another one

Tags: python, unix, sorting, header

I have to remove the first 2 headers of many files and replace them with another one. As I am new to Python and programming, I have been using the following code

```
import glob
import os
list_of_files = glob.glob('./*.txt')
for file_name in list_of_files:
    os.system('sed "1,2d" %s | sort -k1 > %s.sort' %(file_name,file_name))
    os.system ('cat header file %s.sort > %s.header' %(file_name,file_name))
```

which works. However I think there should be a better way of getting this done. Also I am unnecessarily making an extra file *.sort which I don't require.

Comment: at the very least, you can sed in place with the -i flag.

Comment: @Anov ...which makes you lose the original file.

Comment: @glglgl you can send a extension flag other than '' and it will create a backup. As OP said he was "unnecessarily making an extra fil *.sort" I assumed he didn't need to keep the original.

Comment: @Anov -- The `sort` file might be unnecessary, but there are 3 files here (`file`, `file.sort` and `file.header`)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Believe it or not, you can do this pretty easily in pure python:

```
import itertools
with open(filename) as fin:
    ilines = itertools.islice(fin, 2, None) #this throws away the first 2 lines
    lines = sorted(ilines, key=lambda x: x.split()[0])  #sort lexicographically on first column

with open('header') as header, open('%s.header'%filename) as fout:
    fout.writelines(header) #write the header
    fout.writelines(lines) #write the data
```

You're done.  Take a slightly longer lunch break because python helps you save time* :-).

*(Alternatively, spend some of your long lunch learning more of the cool things python has to offer!)

Happy Coding!

Comment: @glglgl -- You're just editing all of my answers today, aren't you ;-)

Comment: @glglgl -- I'm sure if you looked back through my old answers, you'd find enough to get yourself a Copy Editor badge :p

Comment: No, I normally just correct things I find spontaneously. If I'd search for them all over SO, I would probably get a heart attack :-P But please don't call me Sheldon Cooper nor Adrian Monk. Thank you. *g*

Answer (score 1):

Avoid `os.system`.

A first approach could be

```
import glob
import subprocess
list_of_files = glob.glob('./*.txt')
for file_name in list_of_files:
    sp1 = subprocess.Popen(['sed', '1,2d', file_name], stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
    sp2 = subprocess.Popen(['sort', '-k1'], stdin=sp1.stdout, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
    out = open(file_name + '.header', 'w')
    sp3 = subprocess.Popen(['cat', 'header', 'file', '-'], stdin=sp2.stdout, stdout=out)
    sp1.stdout.close() # sp2 got it, not our business any longer
    sp2.stdout.close() # sp3 got it, not our business any longer
    out.close()
    sp1.wait()
    sp2.wait()
    sp3.wait()
```

Comment: ... as said, a first approach. [mgilson's solution](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13882120/296974) is better by far, as it is does all the stuff natively instead of calling other programs.